# MTB Sizing. Saddle at the very bottom to reach pedals perfectly. Go one size smaller?

Tags: mountain-bike

So im buying my first MTB. Its a Scott Scale 930. With the size M i get the perfect reach to the pedal with my heel. But only when the saddle is set to the very lowest/bottom. Should i get a size S instead? My height is 171 cm.

Thnx

Comment: The ideal size depends on more than just the length of your legs. How does, for example, the position of the handlebars compare for you between the two frames?

Comment: Im not even sure how its supposed to feel to answer that. Both felt natural. I think i was more leaned over on the M size.

Comment: I'd guess that you're going to need to get the small, but this is a *lot* of money for a first mountain bike. Note that you can tweak the fit with different sized stuff, like longer stems and longer seatposts if necessary (but if you're at the bottom on a medium, chances are you're somewhere in the middle on a small).

Comment: Whats your intended use? For commuting and easy off road medium would be a good choice. For technical single track consider the smaller frame.  At 171cm, I am surprised the medium is so large on you. I am 174 and ride a medium Spark with 200mm exposed seat post for technical single track (would lift another 25mm or more for 'road' ).

Comment: So ive measured my inner leg. And on a medium i have 2.6 inch standover clearence on a small i have 3.7 inch clearence. Does that give any indication to which i should chose? (Realized i can cut the saddletube anyway)

Comment: Im 5'7 and have 32-33" inner leg

Comment: I presumed in my early answer that "All the way down" meant "All the way down". Trimming the seat tube is a common requirement, you LBS will do this for you when you buy the bike, but I suggest not trimming and riding a few weeks before committing to it.

Comment: You should also bear in mind that when riding offroad we often drop the saddle for a technical descent. Can't do that if it's already at the bottom of its travel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have to put the saddle all the way down, the frame is too <strike>small</strike> large. You need to have a comfortable clearance between the top tube and your crotch when your feet are flat on the ground - especially on an off-road bike, since you'll often have to dismount in a hurry. There are other aspects to getting a proper fit, but this is something you can't get around.

Also, if you're on the short end of things, I wouldn't recommend a 29er. They do make them in small sizes, but in order to get a smaller rider into a reasonable riding position between those two big wheels, they have to make some compromises with the geometry. You'd be better off with 26" or 27.5" wheels.

Comment: "If you have to put the saddle all the way down, the frame is too small". Don't you mean that the frame is too big?

Comment: @BSOrider Yes, of course. Corrected.

Comment: You should also mention that on MTB we often drop the saddle for descents. This is hard to do when it's already on the rails!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with some other comments in that I think you should go for a small. You can change a lot on a bike and unless you go down the custom frame route, you will need to mod things to achieve the perfect position. The saddle to pedal/Bottom bracket interface is just the start. Get that wrong and you are floating down a creek without a paddle. Try the small and feel the difference when the saddle is set right in relation to the pedals. Hope it helps some.

Comment: So ive measured my inner leg. And on a medium i have 2.6 inch standover clearence on a small i have 3.7 inch clearence. Does that give any indication to which i should chose? (Realized i can cut the saddletube anyway)

Comment: Im 5'7 and have 32-33" inner leg.

Answer (score 1):

On that style of bike saddle in the lowest position is OK.  On the size cart you are right in between.  Ask the shop.  Hopefully they will let you ride both.